# Not sure why my for loop isn't working the way i intended it to

Tags: java, for-loop

So, before I start I just wanted to say that I'm very new to Java as a language and I've been reading a text book that was recommended to me.
One of the examples provided within the text book on for loops had the following code, which is meant to generate an infinite for loop until the user presses the character 'S' on their keyboard.

Here is the code:

```
class ForTest {
    public static void main(String args[])
        throws java.io.IOException {
            int i;
            System.out.println("Press S to stop.");
            for (i = 0; (char) System.in.read() != 'S'; i++) 
                System.out.println("Pass #" + i);
                
        }
}
```

I copied the code exactly as it was written within the book but when I run the program, to my surprise, it doesn't start printing out numbers onto the console. Additionally, whenever I press any keys on the keyboard it generates three numbers within the sequence. Example shown below:
[image]

I have also included a screenshot of the code from the book below:
[image]

I was wondering whether anyone knows why this is the case!
Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks.

Comment: This is a bizzare approach compared to most introductions to Java. Consider a different textbook.

Comment: "until the user presses the character 'S' on their keyboard" they forgot to add "and presses Enter"

Comment: it won't print numbers unless you press a key and then enter

Comment: But how come when I press a key other than S lets say A, it doesnt continue printing infinitely?
Instead it just prints out 3 iterations of i

Comment: infinitely just means that each time you press a key you will get a number, until you press S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it's printing multiple times is because multiple characters are detected.
In your case, it's printing twice because you entered a value (**Pass 1**) and a new line (**Pass 2**)

The problem you have is not with System.in.read(), but because the console is usually using a buffered approach. Meaning that data is only transferred to the `System.in.read()` once you press enter.

So to get the example working, you would have to switch the console to an unbuffered mode, but there is no portable way to do this, because there are so much different types of consoles. Maybe have a look at what editor/console the book is using

Comment: Thank u so much for your answer. I just realised that my output in fact prints out 3 iterations of i instead of 2. (I have included an example of this). Do you know why the third iteration is done?

Comment: This could depend on the system you are using. Some systems use ´\n´ for new lines, others use ´\r\n´. I've tested your code on my system, and it only returns 2 lines for one character + newline

Comment: Though as @Jems said, it's a bizzarre approach compared to most introduction books to Java.

Comment: the book is called "Java: A beginners guide" by Herbert Schildt. I read quite few reviews on it. Do you recommend any other books?

Answer (score 0):

This block of code looks like it was written by someone who was deliberately trying to make it obtuse and difficult to comprehend for a beginner.

The middle expression of a `for` statement is the criterion for taking the next step of the loop. It is evaluated before each step of the loop to determine whether the for loop is complete yet. In this case, it calls `in.read()` and checks if the input is `S` before each step of the loop.

`in.read()` waits for the next line of input it gets. When you enter a value and press Enter, that line gets read, so the loop takes a step. And a new line is also entered, so the loop takes a second step.

It will not print lines to the console unless you enter lines, because `in.read()` causes the program to block (wait) for the next input.

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for the explanation, i made an edit to my original post, i realised that in fact it prints out 3 statements whenever I enter a key. As you explained, the first iteration is for the original character entered and the second step is for the "new line"? what is the reason behind the third iteration?

Comment: `System.in.read()` reads one byte of data at a time. Maybe the number of bytes is more than two for whatever you are typing into the console. The new line might be CRLF (two bytes) or a simple LF (one byte) depending on what platform you're running on.